# Sklearn predict multiple outputs with str & int

Tags: python, scikit-learn

With this code, there is an error!

```
import re
import sklearn
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

from sklearn import tree
import numpy as np

# Dataset & labels
# features = [height, weight, style]
# styles = ['modern', 'classic']
features = [['1.65', '65', 'm'], 
            ['1.55', '50', 'm'],
            ['1.76', '64', 'm'],
            ['1.72', '68', 'c'],
            ['1.73', '68', 'c'],
            ['1.68', '77', 'c']]
labels =    ['Yellow dress',
            'Red dress',
            'Blue dress',
            'Green dress',
            'Purple dress',
            'Orange dress']

# Decision Tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)

# Returns the dress
height = input('Height: ')
weight = input('Weight: ')
style = input('Modern [m] or Classic [c]: ')

print(clf.predict([[height,weight,style]]))
```

error:

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'm'
```

This error is related with different data in type, how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably by changing the type

Comment: Where do you use `OrdinalEncoder ` ? You imported it but I cannot see it

Comment: It's true, I didn't use OrdinalEncoder. In this code, It's not need.

Comment: since you downvoted my answer, I deleted it, although it solved your problem. This is no way to communicate with people who are trying to help you!

Comment: I'm so sorry.but your answer did'nt solve it.
some people said me for solving, i should encode the "m" and "c".
but I could not understand how is it!
best regaurd.